# What are these Indonesian instruments?

Tags: instruments

I once had a record called *Music from the Morning of the World*, which was all Indonesian music. It was very short on sleeve-notes and I never could work out what [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M20qyW2ic2Q&list=OLAK5uy_lveVsIm0UcUJAPh2D9PRCAZ3V6S5Dbufs&index=2) [From 3'23"] instruments were. I think the piece is called *Frog Song*. They sound like one-note mouth organs. They don't seem to appear in Gamelans. Any ideas?

Comment: "The video is not available". But the caption says "flute"

Comment: Curious! Sorry, Todd. Are others finding the same thing? The flute solo is the NEXT piece on the clip, a minute later. Maybe 'Frog Song' is the name of the mouth-organy piece. I'll see if it exists elsewhere.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgsbmzUvIs at 3'23" Please tell me *this* one works!

Comment: Do you mean the jaw harp sound? If so, it is a jaw harp.

Comment: No. Yes, those are at 26". But the things I'm interested are at 3'23". (That's the start of the piece. The mouth-organ things come in 3" later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no [free reed](https://www.patmissin.com/history/eastern.html)  instruments native to Bali. These are most likely [sompotons](https://www.patmissin.com/history/sompoton.html) imported from Borneo.

Comment: Thanks. Your sompton (sompoton?) does sound about right, and Borneo's close enough for the Balinese to have borrowed it. But doesn't the clip sound to you as if each musician has only one note? If not I guess they're not hocketting.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I can't imagine amateur musicians hocketting that accurately.